# Почему не адаптируется, Bootstrap классами контактная форма на сайте WP?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, bootstrap, wp-plugin

Есть сайт. Разместил там форму для регистрации людей на мероприятие с помощью плагина Contact Form 7:

```css
div.wpcf7 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div.wpcf7-response-output {
  margin: 2em 0.5em 1em;
  padding: 0.2em 1em;
}

div.wpcf7 .screen-reader-response {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

div.wpcf7-mail-sent-ok {
  border: 2px solid #398f14;
}

div.wpcf7-mail-sent-ng {
  border: 2px solid #ff0000;
}

div.wpcf7-spam-blocked {
  border: 2px solid #ffa500;
}

div.wpcf7-validation-errors {
  border: 2px solid #f7e700;
}

.wpcf7-form-control-wrap {
  position: relative;
}

span.wpcf7-not-valid-tip {
  color: #f00;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: block;
}

.use-floating-validation-tip span.wpcf7-not-valid-tip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 20%;
  z-index: 100;
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
  background: #fff;
  padding: .2em .8em;
}

span.wpcf7-list-item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 0 1em;
}

span.wpcf7-list-item-label::before,
span.wpcf7-list-item-label::after {
  content: " ";
}

.wpcf7-display-none {
  display: none;
}

div.wpcf7 .ajax-loader {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url('../../images/ajax-loader.gif');
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 4px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

div.wpcf7 .ajax-loader.is-active {
  visibility: visible;
}

div.wpcf7 div.ajax-error {
  display: none;
}

div.wpcf7 .placeheld {
  color: #888;
}

div.wpcf7 .wpcf7-recaptcha iframe {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

div.wpcf7 input[type="file"] {
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.wpcf7 input[type="file"]:disabled {
  cursor: default;
}
.regform {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-md-offset-0 col-lg-offset-0 col-xs-offset-0 col-sm-offset-0 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 hidden-sm hidden-xs visible-md visible-lg">
<div role="form" class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f4180-p10709-o1" lang="en-US" dir="ltr">
    <div class="screen-reader-response"></div>
    <form action="/#wpcf7-f4180-p10709-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate="novalidate">
        <div style="display: none;">
            <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="4180"><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="4.9"><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="en_US"><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f4180-p10709-o1"><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_container_post" value="10709">
        </div>
        <p id="myformpad">Оставьте заявку на участие в игре:</p>
        <p id="myformpad">Ваше имя<br>
            <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name"><input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span> </p>
            <p id="myformpad">Ваш номер телефона<br>
                <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap tel1"><input type="tel" name="tel1" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-tel wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-tel" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span> </p>
                <p id="myformpad"><input type="submit" value="Отправить" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit"><span class="ajax-loader"></span></p>
                <p id="myformpad"><a id="myformlink" href="http://www.cashflow.top/privacy-policy/">Мы гарантируем конфиденциальность</a></p>
                <div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Не могу никак ее адаптировать под разные разрешения - не работает центрирование (`col-xs-12 col-sm-12 или col-xs-10 col-sm-10 + col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1`). Padding-left или margin-left в процентах - тоже не рабочий вариант.

Весь контент сайта меняет свои размеры при применении Bootstrap класов кроме этой формы! Уже очень долго копаюсь в ней и много чего перепробовал - не получается!

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Скорее всего у самого тэга `form` фиксированная ширина, либо у его элементов. Вы бы лучше выложили конечную верстку после преобразований wp.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю. Весь код сайта или скриншот?

Comment: Код формы, генерируемый wp, и css, ответственный за форму

Comment: Вот, стили формы и код.

Comment: 1. Избавьтесь от повторяющегося id в теге p, если на нем висят стили, замените на класс, или наследуйте стили от формы. 2. Не увидел все стили, в частности, `col-xs-12 col-sm-12 или col-xs-10 col-sm-10 + col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1`. 3. SO не место для ссылок, но Вы можете скинуть мне ссылку на сайт, если он есть, иначе так долго можно дискутировать. Надеюсь, участники и модераторы понимают это.

Comment: У самого тэга в который была взята form была фиксированная ширина. Исправил и все стало нормально. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: А как пометить что ответ есть? Где эту галочку поставить?

Comment: К сожалению, на вопрос не было дано ни одного ответа (они ниже размещаются, а не в комментариях), поэтому отметить Вы не сможете